# Create half vertical oval using css

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create an vertical semi oval shape using css. 
I am using the following code to create a full vertical oval

```
#oval {
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;
    -moz-border-radius: 50px / 100px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 50px / 100px;
    border-radius: 50px / 100px;
    position: relative;
}
```

but I want to create it as only left part of this oval(like a 'D')
I trie using the following code but it gives me blunt edges.

```
#oval2{
    height:200px;
    width:50px;
    border-radius: 0% 100% 100% 0%;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 100% 100% 0;
    -webkit-border-radius:  0 100% 100% 0;
    background:green;
}
```

I want sharp edges as in a full oval . How can I achieve the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like so:

```
#oval {
    width: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    background: red;

    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 100px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px 100px;

    position: relative;
}
```

Note: I have set the properties of the corners independently as explained in the article: [Border-radius: create rounded corners with CSS!](http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/).

See [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VCB94/).

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can't use percentages to achieve (at least not for now) this but as long as you know your dimensions you'll be fine. You can do it like this: **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/k4r4F/)**

```
#oval2 {
    height:200px;
    width: 50px;
    border-top-right-radius: 50px 100px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 50px 100px;
    background:green;
}
```

The W3C spec. indicates that `border-radius: 100%` should work as you'd like but it doesn't in chrome **[W3C spec.](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#corner-shaping)**

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code ,it will be helps you:

```
#oval {
width: 70px;
height: 100px;
background: red;
position: relative;
border-top-right-radius: 50px;
border-bottom-right-radius: 50px;
}
```